# How To Stop Tomcat/Java Wrapping My Output

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I've got a JSP page that I want to return a fragment of HTML.  The trouble is that whenever I request the JSP, something is attempting to make the HTML more valid by wrapping <html> tags around it.  I don't want it to do this though as it will be used in a variety of other places.

For an example, the following JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<script src="${applicationConfig.javascriptUrl}update.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<p>Wibble</p>
```

Will result in the following HTML:

```
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><script src="http://fisher.mycompany.com:8080/my-app/includes/js/update.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<p>Wibble</p></html>
```

I really don't want those <html> & <head> tags there and would like to get rid of them but have no idea where this is happening to turn it off. Does anyone have any clues?

*** Edit ***

To give a little more information on what I am trying to achieve.  This JSP will check a variety of things and form a piece of HTML.  This HTML can then be included into other applications via a web service call.

Comment: any other framework that can be doing this? I'm sure tomcat is.

Comment: Couldn't you just supply the correct surrounding tags yourself?

Comment: @Bozho - It's just straight Tomcat & JSPs so no other frameworks are involved.

Comment: @Heiko I certainly could do but I'm curious if there's a better place to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Servlets can return any content type including javascript and images, not just HTML. Tomcat should not wrap jsps in extraneous tags. I put the snippet you suggested in a jsp, minus the taglib which I don't have set up, and got back exactly the HTML that I put in.

Can you tell us more about your environment? Are you using tomcat? Are you using some kind of framework?

Comment: Interesting that you didn't get back the extra tags.  It's running on Tomcat 6 (6.0.29) to be exact. Seam is included on the classpath but this should only be affecting pages with .xhtml extensions according to the web.xml.  I'll delve into my classpath further. Something is obviously doing something I don't know about.

Comment: Found it on a second closer look.  Someone had a Seam filter touching every file for some reason. Thanks for helping me track down what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Servlets are HTML factories.  They expect to send a valid HTML page down to a browser to be rendered.  You can't "get rid of it" without breaking the whole model.

Your original concept of sending a snippet that's "used in a variety of other places" is flawed.  You sound like to want to set some data that might be used in other places - that's valid - but I don't see how wrapping it in markup matters.

Only the JSP should be using the marked up data.  JSPs are all about display.  I'd rethink what you're doing and attack how you want to share the data, not the markup.

Comment: I realise this isn't the best way, but I may be stuck with it.  The markup matters in this case as what is being returned is part of a company wide, single sign on system. The markup is as important as the data as we want a consistent look & feel. Allowing each product to take the data & create the markup themselves each time will probably lead to inconsistencies.  Changing something will also mean changes to many applications, not just this HTML/JSP fragment.

Answer (score 0):

One approach it might work, 
Create HTML files as you required valid HTML, 
and use servlet to returns response, servlet should read HMTL File and return 
its contents as String, like XML respones from servlet

hopes thats helps